# Extra space on top of text in textview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I've defined my layout something like this -

`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/first_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/square" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/second_big_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_icon"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/square_big" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/line1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/second_big_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/second_big_image"
    android:text="AND Here is the text" />
```

`

And on screen I see it something like this. I don't understand why there is a bit of space on top of the text. Even if I'm aligning it to top of the second image it is still not aligned. How do I do it?

[image]

I've already tried `android:alignParentTop="true"` and also `android:gravity="top"`. But nothing seems to be working. May be this is the behavior of android textview but I still want to get rid of that space.

Setting `android:layout_marginTop="-4dip"` makes it appear like what I want. But is it the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think Text view has no problem it is attached to the top (see image image Textview has setted with red BG). The problem is with the Font a you can see the second line also has the gap from the first line so this space is attached with font can try other custom font to check this.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

That space is just the spacing of the font. It has a slight bit of space above it, as does any font (in this case, I guess that's `4dp`).

The only way I can think of to achieve what you want (aside from what you tried) is this:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

If that doesn't work, I'd just do it the way you're doing it now (with the negative top margin).

Ah, the joy of fonts and displays! ^_^

Comment: android:includeFontPadding="false" is little helps.not perfect

Comment: I wondering why they won't let you line up text top to the edge of the layout window.  Why google has to put in some buffering.  Wish they would change that.

Comment: I was banging my head on a wall trying to figure out how to center the letter "S" inside a small circle. It always appeared with a bit too much space on top. This worked!